# Assign domain values to the fields in MS SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, edit

I want to assign domain values to some columns in my `SQL Server` database to provide control to the data. How can I achieve that? I connected to the `SQL Server` database using `PHP PDO` and created the "Edit" option that allows the users to update the values.

How can I create dropdown options with a placeholder in that Edit file?

```
require_once('database.php');

if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    $id = $_POST['txt_id'];
    $site = $_POST['txt_site_code'];

    if (!empty($site)) {

        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE FACILITY_TABLE_MILWAUKEE SET Site_Code=:site
                        WHERE OBJECTID = :id");

            $stmt->execute(array(':site' => $site, ':id' => $id));

            if ($stmt) {
                header('Location:index.php');
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} 
else {
    echo "Input Site Code";
}
    $object_id = 0;
    $site = '';

 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM FACILITY_TABLE_MILWAUKEE WHERE OBJECTID=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $object_id = $row['OBJECTID'];
    $site = $row['Site_Code'];
}

<h2>Edit the records</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table border="3px" cellpadding="5px">
        <tr>
            <td>Site Code</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txt_site_code"  value="<?= $site; ?>" readonly></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="txt_id" value="<?= $object_id; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I have just included first two columns of the table. The table is huge. The last column of the table is "Action" where "Edit" option apperars.

Comment: please show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey Ishita, I just added my codes. The table has too many columns, so I just included first two here. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!